# irregular time series using ggplot2 plot is not correctly scaled and looks crammed

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, xts, zoo

I have some stock hourly data that I want to plot using ggplot2; I will do TSA on it and would like to add layer to the original plot afterwards.

an example of my data looks like below:

```
                   Date Volume
1   2018-03-01 10:30:00 143432
2   2018-03-01 11:30:00  93522
3   2018-03-01 12:30:00 152178
4   2018-03-01 13:30:00 117424
5   2018-03-01 14:30:00 268167
6   2018-03-01 15:30:00 245504
7   2018-03-01 15:59:00 288977
8   2018-03-02 10:30:00 230484
9   2018-03-02 11:30:00 265244
10  2018-03-02 12:30:00 183313
11  2018-03-02 13:30:00 130850
12  2018-03-02 14:30:00 139846
13  2018-03-02 15:30:00 257797
14  2018-03-02 15:59:00 261628
15  2018-03-05 10:30:00 140620
16  2018-03-05 11:30:00 171228
17  2018-03-05 12:30:00 118685
18  2018-03-05 13:30:00 107209
19  2018-03-05 14:30:00 116918
20  2018-03-05 15:30:00 225035
```

I have created a `zoo` object (I Know we could also use `xts` or `irts`):

```
temp <- read.csv('somefile.csv')
zt <- zoo(x = temp, order.by = as.POSIXct(temp$Date))
```

I then tried creating a ggplot object by:

```
a <- ggplot(data = zt, aes(x = index(zt), y = coredata(zt)))
a + geom_line()
```

the plot looked like below:

[image]

Apparently it is not correctly scaled and the plot is very crammed up.

How do I correctly plot it using ggplot2?

I know from some help that I can use `chart_series` from `quantmod` to plot it but I am not sure that function is designed for time series analysis (probably more for financial data plotting) and therefore may not be flexible enough for adding on layers.

**EDIT**

typically I would like to have my plot looking like this:

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
xxt <- xts(x = temp$Volume, order.by = as.POSIXct(temp$Date))
chart_series(xxt)
```

[image]

I don't need all the aesthetics, just the way it plotted is what I wanted. it feels like the `quantmod` chart has removed all the gaps.

Comment: Looks right to me. What did you expect it to look like You have gaps in the data (weekends?) causing the long slopes in the figure

Comment: @RichardTelford I have edited the question with a plot from `quantmod`; it is basically what I wanted, but just the data plot itself; it's easy to tell the difference.

Comment: You basically need to do (by hand, I fear) what `chartSeries` as well as `plot.xts` (with the option @JoshuaUlrich showed you) do: plot with _just the data index as the x axis_ but then use the time stamps as the labels. Not trivial.  Also not sure if there is a `ggplot2` extension that does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried for 45 minutes to get `ggplot` to play nicely and came up empty. I'll talk to the 'zoo' team about adding an option `autoplot.zoo()` so you can just call `autoplot(zt, new.option = TRUE)` to generate the plot you want.

---

You are correct that `quantmod::chart_Series()` is primarily for financial time series.  It looks like you are familiar with zoo and xts, which are data classes that support any time series.

You can use `plot.xts()`. Be sure to set `observation.based = TRUE` so that the x-axis will have equal amount of space between observations, regardless of the amount of time between them.

```
# reproducible data
x <- structure(c(143432L, 93522L, 152178L, 117424L, 268167L, 245504L, 288977L,
230484L, 265244L, 183313L, 130850L, 139846L, 257797L, 261628L, 140620L, 171228L,
118685L, 107209L, 116918L, 225035L), .Dim = c(20L, 1L),
index = structure(c(1519921800, 1519925400, 1519929000, 1519932600, 1519936200,
1519939800, 1519941540, 1520008200, 1520011800, 1520015400, 1520019000,
1520022600, 1520026200, 1520027940, 1520267400, 1520271000, 1520274600,
1520278200, 1520281800, 1520285400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")
```

Now call `plot()` on the xts object.

```
plot(x, observation.based = TRUE, major.ticks = "hours")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your time! And it’ll be great to have an official solution that fits for this purpose, I’ll be looking out for the updates from zoo package :) thanks again!